# Ensuring consistent formatting across plotly express bar polar subplots

Tags: python, plotly, polar-coordinates

I would like to create subplots of plotly express barpolar plots whereby the layout specifications are the same for each plot.

I have taken a solution found in this thread to build the barpolar subploots: [how can i create subplots with plotly express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56727843/how-can-i-create-subplots-with-plotly-express/72588847#72588847?newreg=7369110c018d43b1b55e1f0012ce6fbd)

In the output from this solution, the setting of each subplots is different: the direction of the angular axes vary by subplot and the labels / tickvalues of the angular radius are also different. I am trying to find a way to override these parameters so that I can ensure both subplots have the same settings.

I have tried to use 'fig.update_layout' to set the formatting across all subplots but this doesn't work.

Example data to reproduce one subplot:

```
Age_months | Feed_Volume_ml |  Feed_Hour_Degrees
0              120             15
0              160             90
0              100             90
0              50             270
0              75             270
0              40             300
```

Here is my code:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import plotly.express as px
    from plotly.offline import plot
    from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

    figures = [
                px.bar_polar(fd.loc[fd['Age_months'] == 0].sort_values(by = ['Feed_Volume_ml']), 
                       r = "Feed_Volume_ml", 
                       theta = "Feed_Hour_Degrees", 
                       color = "Feed_Volume_ml",
                       title = "Clock Map of Feeding - Month 0",
                       direction = "clockwise",
                       start_angle = 90,
                       range_r = (0,220)),
               px.bar_polar(fd.loc[fd['Age_months'] == 5].sort_values(by = ['Feed_Volume_ml']), 
                       r = "Feed_Volume_ml", 
                       theta = "Feed_Hour_Degrees", 
                       color = "Feed_Volume_ml",
                       title = "Clock Map of Feeding - Month 5",
                           direction = "clockwise",
                           start_angle = 90,
                           range_r = (0,220) )
            ]

    fig = make_subplots(cols = len(figures), rows=1, 
                        specs= [[{"type": "barpolar"},{"type": "barpolar"}]]) 

    for i, figure in enumerate(figures):
        for trace in range(len(figure["data"])):
            fig.add_trace(figure["data"][trace], row=1, col=i+1,)
        
        
    fig.update_layout(
        polar = dict(
            radialaxis = dict(
                showticklabels = False),
            angularaxis = dict(
                tickvals = np.arange(0,360,15),
                ticktext = ticktexts,
                direction = "clockwise",
            )
        )
    )
        
    plot(fig)`
```

[image: example subplot output]

Comment: Can you post the current output graph and the smallest data that can reproduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple subplots of polar coordinates are created, each with as many polar axes as there are subplots. Therefore, `fig.update_layout(polar=...,polar2=...)` is required.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

figures = [
            px.bar_polar(fd.loc[fd['Age_months'] == 0].sort_values(by = ['Feed_Volume_ml']), 
                   r = "Feed_Volume_ml", 
                   theta = "Feed_Hour_Degrees", 
                   color = "Feed_Volume_ml",
                   title = "Clock Map of Feeding - Month 0",
                   direction = "clockwise",
                   start_angle = 90,
                   range_r = (0,220)),
           px.bar_polar(fd.loc[fd['Age_months'] == 5].sort_values(by = ['Feed_Volume_ml']), 
                   r = "Feed_Volume_ml", 
                   theta = "Feed_Hour_Degrees", 
                   color = "Feed_Volume_ml",
                   title = "Clock Map of Feeding - Month 5",
                       direction = "clockwise",
                       start_angle = 90,
                       range_r = (0,220) )
        ]

fig = make_subplots(cols = len(figures), rows=1, 
                    specs= [[{"type": "barpolar"},{"type": "barpolar"}]]) 

for i, figure in enumerate(figures):
    for trace in range(len(figure["data"])):
        fig.add_trace(figure["data"][trace], row=1, col=i+1,)
    
polar_dict = polar=dict(radialaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
                        angularaxis = dict(tickvals = np.arange(0,360,15),
                                           ticktext = [f'{x}' for x in np.arange(0,360,15)],
                                           direction = "clockwise",)
                       )

fig.update_layout(polar=polar_dict, polar2=polar_dict)

fig.show()
```

[image]